# BluePrism Spy element uniquely

Tags: blueprism, rpa

I am spying one button from one browser based application. But I am getting the error saying more than one item found.

I am able to spy it only under the Accessibility Mode.
Although,I can see in my page that there is only one element in my page.

How to refer my element uniquely under Accessibility Mode as there is no exact path to specify.

Comment: Please make a screen shot of both the web page and of the attributes fround in application modeller. Would limit the posibilities a lot :)

Also, why use AA when you can use HTML. Press Alt while spying to change mode.

Answer (score 5):

If you are not able to see the elements, but Blue Prism is saying that there is more than one element found, then you may have unchecked these two attributes:

- Visible
- Screen Visible

Try setting them as "True", and please check if that will help with your problem.

Different approach would be to use one of these two:

- Match Index
- Ordinal

In a nutshell, they tell Application modeller about which item should be used, if there are multiple similar object visible.

Answer (score 1):

I think it happens when you are having two fields having same properties like in a login page, username & password have same properties when you spy these elements using Blue Prism it shows the error.So, to get rid of that error, check the box ordinal in the application modeller popup(which opens after clicking ctrl+left click) after you've spied the element.I hope you got it.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we spy elements it is recommended to uncheck few attributes like parent url, input identifier, title etc. 
"if there is an error stating that more than one matching window found" then at this point we have to uncheck "windows text" and check the ordinal attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below in Application module

1. Uncheck the checkbox with empty values
2. Uncheck the ParentURL.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check the `Match Index` and `Ordinal` property of the spied element. `Ordinal` will always gives you the unique element on the screen.

This is even mentioned in Blue Prism's Training module.

Answer (score 0):

For Browser/Web-based application, Ordinal Attribute cant not be found.

To Spy the exact element, you can also use "Application Navigator" or UI Automation Navigator.

[image]